# iPhone shows older version of app

Tags: iphone, ios, caching

When I try to run an app on my iPhone via Xcode, it shows an older version then what I am working on - I have changed images and layouts etc.

How do I clear a cache or something just for dev apps?

This hasn't happened to me before. With the simulator it's easy to reset it:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete you app and everything from it's bundle (.app, documents, cache, etc.) will be removed.

If you have an outdated view layout - it's better to check the source-code, the most likely you are launching an outdated version.

Comment: Sweet it works now, ended up clearing my Organizer and cleaned it up from there:-)