# iPhone showing Different to the Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

.

Hello,

First of all, this question may seem similar to my last, but it isn't. For reference if you must compare it is here [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771735/iphone-shows-older-version-of-app)

Now I have developed an app and it runs perfectly on the iPhone Simulator. It does not use anything the Simulator cannot handle.

I have a button, generated in code and it appears on my mac in the simulator, but not on the 2 tested devices. 1) iPhone4 and the 2) iPod Touch 4th Gen.

How is that possible?

```
-(void)popUpMenu
{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu01@2x.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu02@2x.png"];
UIImage *toggledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Done01@2x.png"];
UIImage *toggledSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Done02@2x.png"];

NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, nil];

RNExpandingButtonBar *bar = [[RNExpandingButtonBar alloc] initWithImage:image selectedImage:selectedImage toggledImage:toggledImage toggledSelectedImage:toggledSelectedImage buttons:buttons center:center];

//    RNExpandingButtonBar *bar = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] initWithArray:buttons];


[bar setHorizontal:NO];
[bar setExplode:NO];
[self.view addSubview:bar];
[self setBar:bar];
}
```

The array is a set of buttons that appear from this. The link to the Github is:
[Github - RNExpandingButtonBar](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNExpandingButtonBar)

Then I use this code in viewDidLoad method to display the button

```
[self popUpMenu];
```

Cheers Jeff

Comment: Please add the code that 'generates' the button

Comment: Added the code - it is an image generated button, I have generated those before so I am not sure about this one. The weird thing is the Simulator has no issue at all.

Comment: Check the case of the image names in your code and in your workspace, the device is case sensitive. Could be your problem

Comment: You don't need to append @2x suffix if you have the same images in non-retina version. Moreover be aware with filename, the device is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks iTukker - that was it - if you post it as an answer I can accept it and give you more points :-)

Comment: @Mat - I figured that, but then when I change them in my code I do get different sizes on my device. Do I need to declare it somewhere?

Comment: You should have 2 verions of each image in the bundle, like the Default.png (320x480) and the Default@2x.png (640x960), this for the iPhone; insetad, for universal apps you should also have the iPad versions.

Comment: yeah I got those, that is why I am confused:-) the images are to generate the buttons. The example I used had the retina images, so i generated my own for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the case of the image names in your code and in your workspace, the device is case sensitive and OSX by default is not. Thats why it is working in your simulator and not on your device.